# Angular material complementary

Tags: css, angular, uikit, angular-material, bulma

[Angular material](https://material.angular.io) is awesome but lacks lots of features yet.
So which CSS framework is best to use as a Complementary alongside angular material?

### Edit:

Other Important Factors:

1. Lightweight
2. Responsive
3. Flex support
4. RTL support
5. Modern

Comment: you can use bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)** or **[foundation](https://foundation.zurb.com/)** and instead of using the whole library, you can just load some particular component according to your need so your project doesn't get overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use **Bootstrap** with **ngx-bootstrap** Are Awesome. 
*visite for ngx-bootstrap:* https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/
*and visite for bootstrap:* http://getbootstrap.com/
**thank You**

Comment: ngx-bs\bs4 it's an antitetics solution to am: you use either the one or the other, is not  ok to mix them

Comment: foundation is almost abandoned. Could fit but future uncertain. Better UI-KIT someone said.